# HardDrive Access denied

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-hard-drive

I have a Sony HD SL1 External hard drive. It works on my Samsung TV, and I can view all my data but on my Windows 10 laptop, I am unable to access it. It is displaying "Access Denied" if I try to open it. Formatting is not an option as the data is important.

Comment: Have you been using the hard drive to record something off your TV? If so, it could be that the TV has encrypted the drive to stop you copying things off.

Comment: What file system are you using?  Edit your question, do not submit a comment, and include this vital required information in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an administrator on your laptop and the drive is NTFS, taking possession of the drive should allow you to grant yourself permissions. To accomplish this:

> 1. Connect the drive to your laptop
> 2. Right-click it
> 3. Select Properties
> 4. Click the Security tab
> 5. Click Advanced
> 6. Click Change next to Owner at the top
> 7. Type in your account name in the text box
> 8. Click Check Names and confirm your account (should be hostname\username)
> 9. Click OK
> 10. Check the box for "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects"
> 11. Click Apply
> 12. Click OK

It should run through your drive, giving you permissions to its contents; you should then be able to access all of the folders/files.

Comment: These instructions would only be valid if the file system was NTFS instead of FAT32 which does not have file permissions.